# Actionview::Template::Error with stripe when pushed to heroku

Tags: heroku, actionview, stripe-payments

Folks,

I'm attempting to deploy a rails webapp on Heroku using Stripe. This might be a precompiling asset problem. I checked the heroku error logs and there is an actionview template error "undefined method stripe"

Everything works fine on my local machine, it's just something going wrong when pushing to heroku.

```
2013-02-11T00:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stripe' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000003397440>):
    2013-02-11T00:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: 
    2013-02-11T00:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   </article>
    2013-02-11T00:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:           data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
    2013-02-11T00:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    2013-02-11T00:22:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:           data-description="You'll get your information in 2 days!"
```

Hope someone has some insight in to this issue. I tried just downloading the full stripe.js file and putting it in my assets folder, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be related to asset compilation or `stripe.js`. This is the line that is failing in your view:

```
data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
```

Heroku runs your app with your production environment settings. Is it possible you only have `Rails.configuration.stripe` set in `development.rb`, or somewhere similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was because when I first started testing Stripe on development I had the actual keys in my `stripe.rb` file, so I added it to my `.gitignore` to keep from versioning those keys.  When updated my code to run in production, I used ENV vars instead but forgot to remove the that `stripe.rb` from the `.gitignore`.  Double check to make sure you reconfigure your variables, stop ignore the file, and you should be set.

Comment: This was it for me: stripe.rb was in my .gitignore. Thank you for sharing your personal experience, much appreciated!